# Visual Studio CRT - how to share a static lib used by clients with static and dynamic CRT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msvcrt

If you have the following project structure:

```
 -Shared
 - Exe_Proj1
 - Exe_Proj2
```

Which use the CRT in the following ways:

```
-Shared (Dynamic CRT /MD)
  - Exe_Proj1 (Dynamic CRT /MD)
  - Exe_Proj2 (Static CRT /MT)
```

Then how can you share the "Shared" project with "Exe_Proj2"?

I thought about using /NODEFAULTLIB in shared but this won't change the CRT setting under the "code generation" project settings area.

Answer (score 1):

If `Shared` is a static library, you just can't do it. Make `Exe_Proj2` use the dynamic CRT or die trying.

If `Shared` is a dynamic library, it should work, as long as you don't pass anything that needs the CRT services (any C++ standard library type, file handles, etc.) between the libraries, but in this case the linker shouldn't complain.

Comment: So shared would need to be a DLL which statically links the CRT for this setup to work?

Comment: If shared is a DLL, it needs the same CRT as the client only if they want to exchange CRT-bound stuff (`malloc` in one component, `free` in the other is another example of this); if they don't do that, the DLL can have whatever CRT it wants.